# how to remove outliers prior to multiple imputation

Tags: outliers, psychometrics, multiple-imputation

A colleague came to me with the following problem. She has a complex, multivariate data set, in which respondents completed a number of measures with anywhere from 6 to 30 Likert type items for each measure. She removed the cases with high non-response rates, leaving a data set with occasional missing items, but fairly high overall response.

She is doing a regression analysis on the **total scores** of each measure, but decided to impute individually missing items. She is using multiple imputation in SPSS. She also wants to "handle" her "outliers", by shrinking down outlying scores in some way.

The problem is that she would like to adjust for outliership before imputing, but outliership is evaluated on the basis of the total scores, which are computed after imputation. An additional wrinkle is that SPSS won't allow her to change anything in the imputed samples, wisely assuming the data have been cleaned prior to imputation.

My answer was "No", but my colleague wanted better than that. My view was:

- It's hard to get outliers by averaging over Likert items. Any outlier would only be at the multivariate level, probably because the respondent was genuinely unusual or just being goofy (the study subjects are adolescents), so these people should be flagged, not "normalized".
- I don't like automatic outlier detection (as in everything beyond 3 SD's is an outlier)
- I don't like shrinking outliers down to something more normalesque.

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: First, multiple imputation is all about preserving variation that would otherwise be squashed out by single imputation, so not sure why she's even doing MI except perhaps that it's the only thing SPSS provides. Second, non-stupid imputation is doing modeling, and she wants to post-pre-process her data based on models already fitted, which even SPSS attempts to make difficult. I feel your pain. Is any kind of robust regression possible with MI data in SPSS with Likert-type data? Would she accept that?

Comment: I think you should stand by your training and insist on what is the correct way to go about conducting the data analysis. Removing or (worse) changing outliers solely on the basis of being "outliers" will bias analyses. That is a significant conflict of researcher integrity. I would reintroduce the dropped factors due to high rates of non-response to prevent NMAR data, and I would use unconditional partial-mean-matching models (the default) MI procedure to generate the imputation model.